# multiple levels of catch-all index.php in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 24h;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

This passes everything through /var/www/index.php when any URL is accessed.

I would like, however, for an index.php file in an arbitrary first-level subdirectory to override the root index.php file. i.e.

http://example.com/ -> /var/www/index.php
http://example.com/test -> /var/www/index.php
http://example.com/test/testing -> /var/www/index.php

but **if** /var/www/test/index.php exists:

http://example.com/ -> /var/www/index.php (unchanged)
http://example.com/test -> /var/www/test/index.php
http://example.com/test/testing -> /var/www/test/index.php

I've tried a number of different regexes but am stumped. Any ideas? In Apache this'd be trivial with .htaccess, but that's obviously not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location / {
    if (-e $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    rewrite (.*/)([^\/]+) $1 last;

    try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```

Change *last* to *redirect* for an external redirect instead of an internal rewrite.

Comment: Thank you! Pity it requires an if, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on [h0tw1r3's](https://serverfault.com/a/294085/335434), but without an if:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php?$args @pop;
}

location @pop {
        rewrite (.*/)([^\/]+/?) $1 last;
}
```